# Exception in Keras when trying to use XCeption model as layer in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am getting exception in Keras when I am trying to use model as a layer. My code looks as follows:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import applications
from keras import Input
from keras.models import Model


xception_base = applications.Xception(weights=None,
                                      include_top=False)

left_input = Input(shape=(250, 250, 3))
right_input = Input(shape=(250, 250, 3))

left_features = xception_base(left_input)
right_input = xception_base(right_input)

merged_features = layers.concatenate([left_features, right_input], axis=-1)
model = Model([left_input, right_input], merged_features)
```

Here is the exception I am getting. Not clear to me from the exception what is going wrong

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asattar/workspace/projects/keras-examples/chapter7/MergeTwoModels.py", line 18, in <module>
    model = Model([left_input, right_input], merged_features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Keras-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/network.py", line 224, in _init_graph_network
    assert node_index == 0
AssertionError
```

Can anyone help me with what might be going wrong?

Also there is no error when I do this

```
model = Model(left_input, left_features)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually nvm. I realized that I messed up my variable name

```
right_input = xception_base(right_input)
```

making my graph circular.